# Pandas compare each row to reference row - certain columns only

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, comparison

I have the following Pandas Dataframe**** in Python.

```
   Temp_Fact Oscillops_read         A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H         I         J
0          A          Today  0.710213  0.222015  0.814710  0.597732  0.634099  0.338913  0.452534  0.698082  0.706486  0.433162
1          B          Today  0.653489  0.452543  0.618755  0.555629  0.490342  0.280299  0.026055  0.138876  0.053148  0.899734
2          A          Aactl  0.129211  0.579690  0.641324  0.615772  0.927384  0.199651  0.652395  0.249467  0.262301  0.049795
3          A            DFE  0.743794  0.355085  0.637794  0.633634  0.810033  0.509244  0.470418  0.972145  0.647222  0.610636
4          C    Real_Mt_Olv  0.724282  0.332965  0.063078  0.004550  0.585398  0.869376  0.232148  0.630162  0.102206  0.232981
5          E         Q_Mont  0.221685  0.224834  0.110734  0.397999  0.814153  0.552924  0.981098  0.536750  0.251941  0.383994
6          D            DFE  0.655386  0.561297  0.305310  0.140998  0.433054  0.118187  0.479206  0.556546  0.556017  0.025070
7          F           Bryo  0.257884  0.228650  0.413149  0.285651  0.814095  0.275627  0.775620  0.392448  0.827725  0.935581
8          C          Aactl  0.017388  0.133848  0.939049  0.159416  0.923788  0.375638  0.331078  0.939089  0.098718  0.785569
9          C          Today  0.197419  0.595253  0.574718  0.373899  0.363200  0.289378  0.698455  0.252657  0.357485  0.020484
10         C           Pars  0.037771  0.683799  0.184114  0.545062  0.857000  0.295918  0.733196  0.613165  0.180642  0.254839
11         B           Pars  0.637346  0.090000  0.848710  0.596883  0.027026  0.792180  0.843743  0.461608  0.552165  0.215250
12         B           Pars  0.768422  0.017828  0.090141  0.108061  0.456734  0.803175  0.454479  0.501713  0.687016  0.625260
13         E       Tomorrow  0.860112  0.532859  0.091641  0.768896  0.635966  0.007211  0.656367  0.053136  0.482367  0.680557
14         D            DFE  0.801734  0.365921  0.243407  0.826373  0.904416  0.062448  0.801726  0.049983  0.433135  0.351150
15         F         Q_Mont  0.360710  0.330745  0.598830  0.582379  0.828019  0.467044  0.287276  0.470980  0.355386  0.404299
16         D      Last_Week  0.867126  0.600093  0.813257  0.005423  0.617543  0.657219  0.635255  0.314910  0.016516  0.689257
17         E      Last_Week  0.551499  0.724981  0.821087  0.175279  0.301397  0.304105  0.379553  0.971244  0.558719  0.154240
18         F           Bryo  0.511370  0.208831  0.260223  0.089106  0.121442  0.120513  0.099722  0.750769  0.860541  0.838855
19         E           Bryo  0.323441  0.663328  0.951847  0.782042  0.909736  0.512978  0.999549  0.225423  0.789240  0.155898
20         C       Tomorrow  0.267086  0.357918  0.562190  0.700404  0.961047  0.513091  0.779268  0.030190  0.460805  0.315814
21         B       Tomorrow  0.951356  0.570077  0.867533  0.365708  0.791373  0.232377  0.478656  0.003857  0.805882  0.989754
22         F          Today  0.963750  0.118826  0.264858  0.571066  0.761669  0.967419  0.565773  0.468971  0.466120  0.174815
23         B      Last_Week  0.291186  0.126748  0.154725  0.527029  0.021485  0.224272  0.259218  0.052286  0.205569  0.617701
24         F          Aactl  0.269308  0.655920  0.595518  0.404817  0.290342  0.447246  0.627082  0.306856  0.868357  0.979879
```

I also have a Series of values for each column:

```
df_base = df[df['Oscillops_read'] == 'Last_Week']
df_base_val = df_base.mean(axis=0)
```

As you can see, this is a Pandas Series and it is the average, for each column, over rows where `Oscillops_read == 'Last_Week'`. Here is the Series:

```
[0.56993702256121603, 0.48394061768804786, 0.59635616273775061, 0.23591030688019868, 0.31347492150330231, 0.39519847430740507, 0.42467546792253791, 0.4461465888887961, 0.26026797943899194, 0.48706569569369912]
```

I also have 2 lists:

1.

```
range_name_list = ['Base','Curnt','Prediction','Graph','Swg','Barometer_Output','Test_Cntr']
```

This list gives values that must be added to the dataframe `df` under certain conditions (described below).

2.

```
col_1 = list('DFA')
col_2 = list('ACEF')
col_3 = list('CEF')
col_4 = list('ABDF')
col_5 = list('DEF')
col_6 = list('AC')
col_7 = list('ABCDE')
```

These are lists of column names. These columns from `df` must be compared to the average Series above. So for example, for the 6th list col_6, columns `A` and `C` from each row of the dataframe `df` must be compared to columns `A` and `C` of the Series.

**Problem:**
As I mentioned above, I need to compare specific columns from the dataframe `df` to the base Series `df_base_val`. The columns to be compared are listed in `col_1, col_2, col_3, ..., col_7`. Here is what I need to do:

- if a row for the dataframe column names listed in `col_1` (eg. if a row for columns `A` and `C`) is greater than the base Series `df_base_val` in those 2 columns then for that row, in a new column `Range`, enter the 6th value from the list `range_name_list`.

**Example:**
eg. use `col_6` - this is the 6th list and it has column names `A` and `C`.

1. Step 1: For row 1 of `df`, columns `A` and `C` are greater than
   `df_base_val[A]` and `df_base_val[C]` respectively.
2. Step 2: Thus, for row 1, in a new column `Range`, enter the 6th element from the list `range_name_list` - the 6th element is `Barometer_Output`.

**Example Output:**
After doing this, the 1st row becomes:

```
0          A          Today  0.710213  0.222015  0.814710  0.597732  0.634099  0.338913  0.452534  0.698082  0.706486  0.433162  'Barometer_Output'
```

Now, if this row were NOT to be greater than the Series in columns `A` and `C` and is not greater than the Series in columns from `col_1`, `col_2`, etc. then the `Range` column must be assigned the value 'Not_in_Range'. In that case, this row would become:

```
0          A          Today  0.710213  0.222015  0.814710  0.597732  0.634099  0.338913  0.452534  0.698082  0.706486  0.433162  'Not_in_Range'
```

**Simplification and Question:**
In this example:

1. I only compared the 1st row to the base series. I need to compare
   all rows of `df` individually to the base series and add an appropriate value.
2. I only used the 6th list of columns - this was `col_6`. Similarly, I need to go through each list of column names - `col_1`, `col_2`, ...., `col_7`.
3. If the row being compared is not greater than any of the lists `col_1` to `col_7`, in the specified columns, then the column `Range` must be assigned the value 'Not_in_Range'.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe using loops?

**** to create the above dataframe, select it from above and copy. Then use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print df
```

**EDIT:**
If multiple conditions are met, I would need that they all be listed. i.e. if the row belongs to 'Swg' and 'Curnt', then I would need to list both of these in the Range column, or to create separate Range columns, or just Python lists, for each matching result. Range1 would list 'Swg' and column Range2 would list 'Curnt', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters I would create a dictionary with your condition sets where the keys can be used as indices for your range_name_list list:

```
conditions = {0: list('DFA'),
              1: list('ACEF'),
              2: list('CEF'),
              3: list('ABDF'),
              4: list('DEF'),
              5: list('AC'),
              6: list('ABCDE')}
```

The following code will then accomplish what I understand to be your task:

```
# Create your Range column to be filled in later.
df['Range'] = '|'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for ix, list in conditions.iteritems():
    # Create a list of the outcomes of checking whether the
    # value for each condition column is greater than the 
    # df_base_val average.
    truths = [row[column] > df_base_val[column] for column in list]
    # See if all checks evaluated to True
    if sum(truths) == len(truths):
      # If so, set the 'Range' column's value for the current row
      # to the appropriate 'range_name'
      df.ix[index, 'Range'] = df.ix[index, 'Range'] + range_name_list[ix] + "|"
# Fill in all rows where no conditions were met with 'Not_in_Range'
df['Range'][df['Range'] == '|'] = 'Not_in_Range'
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to post the output dataframe?.When I run this code, for the first 3 rows of the output `df`, it seems that `df.loc[0:3,'F'] < range_name_list[0:3]`.i.e. the column `F` has a value less than the 6th value in `range_name_list` and this should mean that the Range column gets 'Not_in_Range', which it doesn't seem to be doing. All the other columns are working fine from my check of the first 3 rows of the output `df`. It seems like there is only a problem with column F.. For row 1, column `F` is 0.33891, whereas `range_list` has a value of 0.39519867 for its 6th item.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question and was comparing to the wrong df_base_val figure.  Edited and it should suit your needs now.

Comment: Could you explain what the `break` line does? If the `if` statement is satisfied, then the column 'Range' is appropriately populated and you move on to the next row. That seems to all make sense to me. But then why is `break` needed?

Comment: The [break line](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) terminates the for loop so we stop checking conditions.  I wrote that assuming you wanted to stop running through the conditions once one of them had been met entirely.  If you want to instead include all conditions that were met, or only the latest (or something else), the code would have to be revised a bit.

Comment: Oh thanks. Yes, I would actually need to include to include all conditions that were met. I forgot to mention this in the original post. I'll add it there. Is it possible to modify the code so as to include all of them, maybe by adding additional columns - Range1, Range2, Range3, etc.?

Comment: What about just one range column where all are included and pipe-delimited?  Edited the code above as an example.

Comment: Could you explain what you changed? Did you only add this `+ range_name_list[ix] + "|"` or did you also make other changes?

Comment: Yep, so I changed `df['Range'] = '|'` so that the default is a pipe rather than an empty string -- this way the string in the range column ends up being `|condition1|condition2|etc|` based off the change that you noted, which also included taking out the break statement (`+ range_name_list[ix] + "|"`).  Last change is then filling in the rows whose value is '|' rather than '' (`df['Range'][df['Range'] == '|'] = 'Not_in_Range'`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help with this. All questions in this post have been answered.

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)
df_base = df[df['Oscillops_read'] == 'Last_Week']
df_base_val = df_base.mean(axis=0)
columns = ['DFA', 'ACEF', 'CEF', 'ABDF', 'DEF', 'AC', 'ABCDE']
range_name_list = ['Base','Curnt','Prediction','Graph','Swg','Barometer_Output','Test_Cntr']

ranges = pd.Series(["NOT_IN_RANGE" for _ in range(df.shape[0])], index=df.index)

for name, cols in zip(range_name_list, columns):
    cols = list(cols)
    idx = df.index[(df[cols] > df_base_val[cols]).all(axis=1)]
    ranges[idx] = name

print ranges
```

But I don't know what you want if there are multiple range match with one row.

Comment: If multiple ranges match one row, then I would want both names to be added to the 'Range' column as a list. eg. ['Prediction','Graph']. However, could you give an example of when this occurs?

Comment: Any thoughts on when the problem occurs? If you have an example, then that would be great.